If $F(a,b,c)=g_1(a,f_1(b,c))=g_2(b,f_2(c,a))$, then $F(a,b,c)=g_3(c,f_3(a,b))$ for some functions $f_3,g_3$
For a function $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$, I am interested in the following question:
If functions $f_1,g_1,f_2,g_2$ satisfy the identity $$F(a,b,c)=g_1(a,f_1(b,c))=g_2(b,f_2(c,a))$$for all $a,b,c$, must there exist functions $f_3,g_3$ satisfying the identity$$F(a,b,c)=g_3(c,f_3(a,b))$$for all $a,b,c$?

My thoughts:
Suppose $F$ is twice differentiable.
Taking partial derivatives of $F(a,b,c)=g_1(a,f_1(b,c))$ we get
$$F^{0, 0, 1}(a, b, c) F^{1, 1, 0}(a, b, c) - F^{0, 1, 0}(a, b, c) F^{1, 0, 1}(a, b, c) = 0$$
Taking partial derivatives of $F(a,b,c)=g_2(b,f_1(c,a))$ we get
$$F^{1, 0, 0}(a, b, c) F^{0, 1, 1}(a, b, c) - F^{0, 0, 1}(a, b, c) F^{1, 1, 0}(a, b, c) = 0$$
Adding the above two equations, we get
$$F^{1, 0, 0}(a, b, c) F^{0, 1, 1}(a, b, c)-F^{0, 1, 0}(a, b, c) F^{1, 0, 1}(a, b, c) = 0$$
This is a necessary condition for existence of two functions $g_3,f_3$ satisfying the identity $F(a,b,c)=g_3(c,f_3(a,b))$, presumably (under some assumptions) it would be also a sufficient condition.
